# Id is malformed for

Tags: power-automate

I am using "Add a to-do (V3)" to create a new task inside a certain list, whenever I hardcode the string for the To-do List, it works. When I use a dynamic name it throughs this exception

{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
"request-id": "420db67f-3ec2-4490-bf59-c896631f0eea",
"client-request-id": "420db67f-3ec2-4490-bf59-c896631f0eea",
"x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"1","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"CY4PEPF00005257"}}",
"Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
"x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
"x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Date": "Fri, 01 Apr 2022 10:09:21 GMT",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Content-Length": "363"
},
"body": {
"error": {
"code": "invalidRequest",
"message": "Invalid request",
"innerError": {
"code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
"message": "Id is malformed.",
"date": "2022-04-01T10:09:22",
"request-id": "420db67f-3ec2-4490-bf59-c896631f0eea",
"client-request-id": "420db67f-3ec2-4490-bf59-c896631f0eea"
}
}
}
}

Comment: Can you show the action in your flow in the designer? A bit hard to diagnose without seeing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.